# React returning a function in a custom hook, whose internal hook returns an object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I recent upgraded my use-debounce react package. the breaking change was that the hook returned an object instead of an array. I am unable to update the hook so that it works with the new change. [I have created a codesandbox to demonstrate the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/callback-forked-n630o?file=/src/index.js), where setting the state fails, as the setter returned from the hook isnt configured right. For the purpose of the sandbox, i threw the hook component inside the main component so all the info would be in one spot.

The error is `setState is not a function`

Heres the code from the sandbox if you dont feel like looking

```
const Input = () => {
  // hook that would normally be in a seperate component
  const useDebouncedState = (
    initialState,
    durationInMs = 200,
    options = {}
  ) => {
    const [internalState, setInternalState] = useState(initialState);
    const debouncedSetter = useDebouncedCallback(
      () => debouncedSetter.callback(setInternalState),
      durationInMs,
      options
    );
    return [internalState, debouncedSetter];
  };

  // this would be set in the main components
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useDebouncedState("", 200, {
    maxWait: 1000
  });

  // this is where i set
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)} />
      <h1>{searchText}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Input />, rootElement);
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that. "setSearchText is not a function"

Comment: you look at your debounce callback codes, and the codes in the example on use debounced, it's very different. Maybe you should go back to the example again?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this code:

```
const debouncedSetter = useDebouncedCallback(
  // debouncedSetter in this scope is undefined, but linter doesn't catch it
  () => debouncedSetter(setInternalState),
  durationInMs,
  options
);
```

`debouncedSetter` is `undefined` since you never declared it, therefore due to closures it will call `callback()` on `undefined` which causes a runtime error.

If you change your code to the next snippet, you will notice the linting warnings:

```
const useDebouncedState = (initialState, durationInMs = 200, options = {}) => {
  const [internalState, setInternalState] = useState(initialState);
  const callback = useDebouncedCallback(
    // 'debouncedSetter' is not defined
    () => debouncedSetter(setInternalState),
    durationInMs,
    options
  );
  return [internalState, callback];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who posted, it led me to my answer. the working code is

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import useDebouncedCallback from "use-debounce/lib/useDebouncedCallback";

const Input = () => {
  // hook that would normally be in a seperate component
  const useDebouncedState = (
    initialState,
    durationInMs = 200,
    options = {}
  ) => {
    const [internalState, setInternalState] = useState(initialState);
    const debouncedSetter = useDebouncedCallback(
      setInternalState,
      durationInMs,
      options
    );
    return [internalState, debouncedSetter];
  };

  // this would be set in the main components
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useDebouncedState("", 800, {
    maxWait: 1000
  });

  // this is where i set
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => setSearchText.callback(e.target.value)}
      />
      <h1>{searchText}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Input />, rootElement);
```